# problem with relations, does not find properties

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-8

i have a problem with relations, does not find properties,

Error: **Trying to get property 'servicio' of non-object**

Controller:

```
 public function index(Request $personal){


    $personal = Personal::where('nombre' , $personal)->with('nombre')->get();
    $servicios = \App\Models\Eventos::orderByDesc('hora')->get();



    return view('personal', compact('servicios','personal'));

   
  }
```

Model Servicios:

```
    class Servicios extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function eventos()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Evento::class);
    }

    public function personal()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Personal::class);
    }
}
```

Model Eventos:

```
 class Eventos extends Model
{
    protected $table= 'eventos';

    //
    protected $fillable = [
        'titulo', 'descripcion', 'fecha', 'hora', 'prioridad', 'servicio', 'personal',
    ];

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function servicio()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Servicios::class);
    }
    public function personal()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Personal::class);
    }
```

In blade.php:

```
@foreach ($servicios as $hoy)
  <td>{{$hoy->servicio_id->servicio}}</td>
  @endforeach
```

Database:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMepv.png

I do not understand the error so that I do not find the property

Comment: `$hoy->servicio_id` returns 1 or 2 (an `integer`), and `1->servico` or `2->servico` is not valid code... Did you mean `$hoy->servico->servico`? (Table, column and relationship names are a little hard to understand due to being in a different language)

Comment: yes, $hoy->servicio_id returns 1 or 2.   but $hoy->servico->servicio  returns error

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/24qrZAD.png

Comment: What you are trying to do is not valid and confusing. servico_id is an integer not an model.

Comment: yes, It is an integer, it is the number that relates the events table with the services table

Answer (score 2):

In `Laravel` you can access relationships on the function name accessed as a property.

The following should fix your problem. Having relationship `fillable` does nothing.

```
@foreach ($servicios as $hoy)
    <td>{{ $hoy->servicio->servicio_property_to_access }}</td>
@endforeach
```

**Update**

You have a servicio field on your model if i remember correctly that can conflict renaming the relationship might help.

```
class Eventos extends Model
{
    public function servicioRelationship()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Servicios::class);
    }

@foreach ($servicios as $hoy)
    <td>{{ $hoy->servicioRelationship->servicio }}</td>
@endforeach
```

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/yKv8ybV.png print error, it is very confusing

Comment: servicio_property_to_access is a generic property, you should replace it with the property you want to access. servicio is your model, so whatever you want to access on it :)

Comment: can you please include the code you are trying to print with